# Using the 'Match' function in Excel to return a cell address

Tags: excel, reference, match, cell, formula

I have a list of numbers in a table that I would like to search for and bring back the cell reference of where that number resides.  For example the data looks like:

```
        A       B        C        D
1       1       2        3        4
```

ok it doesn't come out very well as the first one is the row number and then each number below sits under each letter, so C1 would contain '3'....

If I wanted to return the reference number of C1 in a cell I am using the formula of `=CELL("address",MATCH(AU14,C1:AG1))` but this just errors.  I have tried to put an Index in there too, but I believe that index only works vertically so this bring back a #N/A result.

Can anyone assist as I've wasted too much time on this already! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make CELL work you need a cell reference, e.g.

```
CELL("address",C1)
```

The trouble is that MATCH just gives you a number, not a cell reference.

Probably the easiest way is to use the ADDRESS function, so a first try might be

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(AU14,C1:AG1,0)+2)
```

That would give you the right answer if AU14 contained 3, but isn't considered to be very good because it wouldn't update if you deleted/inserted rows or columns.

A better one would be

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(C1),MATCH(AU14,C1:AG1,0)+COLUMN(C1)-1)
```

Then you might want to put in some error handling for the case where it's not found

```
=IFERROR(ADDRESS(ROW(C1),MATCH(AU14,C1:AG1,0)+COLUMN(C1)-1),"Not found")
```

Answer (score 5):

You are indeed missing an `INDEX`.  And `INDEX` works vertically, horizontally, or both depending on how it's called.

Here is a formula that works for the ranges in the pictures.  Should be easy to modify.

Formula in `C5`

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(B2:F2,MATCH(C4,B2:F2,0)))
```

**formula**

[image: formula]

**results**

[image: results]

Comment: I like @Byron's version. It works because the INDEX function returns a Reference, which is interpreted as such by the CELL formula +1 https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/INDEX-reference-function-45a7f0a1-1e82-456e-9000-a01daf64e071